# redirect from jquery in flask application

Tags: jquery, flask, redirect

I am using flask to make an application and I made a separate file for jquery (i.e in `static/script/jquery.js`).

I want to redirect to homepage which is in template folder, how can I do that?

I tried: `window.location.href = "{{url_for ('home_page')}}"`

This is not working, here is the error message.

[image: error message]

Comment: Your jquery code fragment is correct. What do you see on inspection of the rendered page? This will tell you if the `url_for()` function is properly expanded.

Comment: So, not found means on server side the template could not be rendered properly. The 'home_page' route was not discovered. Are you using blueprints for grouping your routes, in which case you are missing the first part of the route, e.g. `'landing.home_page'`

Comment: Comment to viewers: marking down a newbie's question is not the best way to encourage learning and growth!

Comment: i want to redirect it to home_page but it is not redirecting it
my flask code 
@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])

def home_page():

    return render_template("home.html")


my jquery code:

            window.location.href = "{{url_for ('home_page')}}"

Comment: is there is any other way so that I can redirect to that page

Comment: Actually, this error indicates that there is no jinja template rendering taking place on the page that contains the `window.location.href`. How are you rendering that page? It also needs to go through the flask route delivery with render_template() applied to the template page/file.

Comment: when i wrote the same command in <script> </script> in html page which is in template folder
it work fine it found the route home_page in flask and redirect me to that page but when I use the same thing by making the separate .js file in static/script it shows the error that the check your spelling

Comment: Yes, the static pages are delivered to the client side without passing through any needed transformations in the `render_template()` function.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, you cannot expect a Jinja2 rendering transformation of a code fragment expressing a route `url_for(..)` when it is passed to the client as an included static page.

You need to ensure that all such transformations are in the main html document delivered to the client side using flask's `render_template()` function.